# UDF to name cells

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to build a `UDF` function to name cells in a spreadsheet.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
Function NameThatCell(TheCell As Range, TheName As String)
    TheCell.Name=TheName
End Function
```

Comment: Use a **sub** not a **udf()**

Comment: Your title refers to you wanting to change the name of a cell but your `Function` is change the name of a **Range**. Now, `Range` can be a cell but just as likely (if not more likely) it will be a collection of cells. Also, when you say **it doesn't work**.. that doesn't tell us a lot. Can you elaborate and tell us what the actual error message you get? (if any). Or why it **doesn't work**? remember, pic speaks a thousand words

Comment: If you are trying to use this as a worksheet function, it won't work. You can't modify the cell, only return a value. If you're calling it from VBA then you can ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to spend some time learning about the difference between a function and a subroutine.

A function returns a value. A function has one or more inputs, then performs a calculation and returns the result of the calculation to the calling instance. That can be a worksheet formula or a call within a VBA routine. A function should never be used to manipulate elements of the worksheet like cells, range names, objects, etc.

A sub (subroutine) can do all kinds of things to elements of the worksheet. It starts, it does things, then it ends. It does not return anything and it can work with all aspects of the workbook. It can even call a function if it needs to get the result of a calculation that is performed in the function.